# React dynamic routes not working after BrowserRouter changes

Tags: reactjs

I refactored my BrowserRouter setup in order to use [react-tiger-transition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tiger-transition) in my app and now dynamic routes aren't working.

**index.js** is straightforward

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

and the structure in **App.js**:

```
Import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import { Navigation, Route, glide } from 'react-tiger-transition'
import 'react-tiger-transition/styles/main.min.css'

import Gallery    from './components/gallery'
import About      from './components/about'
import ViewEntry  from './components/view-entry'
import AddEntry   from './components/add-entry'

function App() {
  return (
    <Navigation>
      <Route exact path='/'>
        <Gallery />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path='/archive'>
        <Gallery />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/new" >
        <AddEntry />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/entry/:singleId" component={ViewEntry} />
      <Route exact path="/about">
        <About />
      </Route>
    </Navigation>
  )
}

export default App
```

Now the ViewEntry component doesn't mount, I just get a blank page. I tried this:

```
<Route path="/entry/:singleId">
  <ViewEntry />
</Route>
```

But get the error `TypeError: match is undefined` in the ViewEntry component.

The relevant bit in ViewEntry is....

```
const ViewEntry = ({ match }) => {
  const { params: { singleId }} = match;
```

I'm still new to React and not experienced enough with dynamic routing to know what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

match is one of the props passed by the router to the route component. You can access things like the url params (i.e `singleId`) using `props.match.params`. So likely it is not being passed (not sure why).

With that being said I suggest you use `react-router`. It is the most popular routing library with 3.7 Million weekly downloads. There is a ton of tutorials out there. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router